# ARM Template - Get a private ip address from a network interface id

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-rm-template

i have a network interface created by ARM template:

```
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaces_test_0_eth0_name')]",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworks_vpc_name'), 'subnet_signaling_int')]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_sg_int_signal_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('networkInterfaces_test_0_eth0_name'), '_static')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAddress": "192.168.0.93",
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworks_vpc_name'), 'subnet_signaling_int')]"
                        },
                        "primary": true,
                        "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('networkInterfaces_test_0_eth0_name'), '_virtual')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAddress": "192.168.0.82",
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworks_vpc_name'), 'subnet_signaling_int')]"
                        },
                        "primary": false,
                        "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "dnsSettings": {
                "dnsServers": []
            },
            "enableAcceleratedNetworking": false,
            "enableIPForwarding": false,
            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_sg_int_signal_name'))]"
            }
        }
    },
```

Now in another arm template i need to retrive the address 192.168.0.82 to set a VM tag, how can i do ?

i set a variable with the inteface id

```
   "variables" : {
  "test" : "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_oam_0_eth0_name'))]"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at all with ARM Templates, you can not retrieve properties of an existing resource (well, you can in a sense with [reference() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference) but it wont work for tags - this works for limited use cases, inside the properties of a resource for instance, not for variables).

What you can do instead, you can use powershell script that would pull this value for you and put this as a parameter in the second ARM template.

Or you can give it a try with Bicep - see [Existing resources in Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource).

Comment: Bicep compiles to ARM, so if its possible in Bicep you can do it in ARM right?